# Submitting default value in text form Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm developing a simple rails app where I want to plot some stock charts. The problem is that when I start my server and load localhost the default value/ticker symbol is not loading which means that I have to type in a ticker in my form for it to work.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608004/how-to-add-default-value-to-a-text-field-in-rails) where I learnt how to write a default value in my form/view, like so:

```
<%= form_for :find_it do |f| %>
Ticker symbol: <%= f.text_field :string, :value => "JPM" %></br>
<%= f.submit "Find" %>
<% end %>
```

and that's all fine, but it does not submit the value by default.

So how do I go about fixing this and what is the best practice?

Comment: It should be submitting that value... what does your parameters look like upon submission?

Comment: Also, is the attribute for `find_it` really `string`? or are you putting its type instead of its name?

Comment: So this may be the problem. Do I need to write it like so? Ticker symbol: <%= f.text_field :find_it, :value => "JPM", :cols => "10", :rows => "1" %></br>

Comment: No, you need to write the attribute to `find_it`, most likely whatever the column name is in the `find_it` table in the database is.

Comment: This was it! Would you be able to write a formal answer so that I can credit you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input field you have list your attribute as a `string`, while that is the type, it most likely isn't the actual name of the attribute you wish to save "JPM".  So you should change

```
<%= f.text_field :string, :value => "JPM" %>
```

to

```
<%= f.text_field :attribute_name, :value => "JPM" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I copy and paste your form into a Rails app on my machine it does display a text field populated with "JPM", which I believe is correct.

When you hit submit the form will post to a `create` action with params containing:

```
"find_it"=>{
  "string"=>"JPM"
}
```

Another thing I noticed is that you have `f.text_field :string`. This should be the name of your attribute, rather than the type (i'm assuming that you don't have a field called string).